# AWS cognito access denied exception

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sts, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

I am trying to view an AWS kinesis video stream on a local web page. However, I keep getting this error.

```
AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::XXXXXXXXX:assumed-role/XXXXXXXX/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: kinesisvideo:GetDataEndpoint on resource: XXXX
```

Here is the policy used for the associated IAM role.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "mobileanalytics:PutEvents",
                "cognito-sync:*",
                "kinesisvideo:*",
                "sts:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using an unauthenticated Cognito role.

I also get a similar exception for sts:assumeRole.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is it working when you give a role withe extended permissions such as Administrator Role ?

Comment: i haven't tried giving it admin permissions, but I have tried with a variety of other roles.